# Error While Configuring Result Source in SharePoint 2013 Site

Tags: 2013, search, result-source

I am getting an error while creating result source programmatically using Console Application.

Below is my code.

```
 using (SPSite oSPsite = new SPSite("http://xxxx/subsite1/"))
        {
            Microsoft.SharePoint.SPServiceContext context = SPServiceContext.GetContext(oSPsite);

            // Get the search service application proxy
            SearchServiceApplicationProxy searchProxy = context.GetDefaultProxy(typeof(SearchServiceApplicationProxy)) as SearchServiceApplicationProxy;
            SearchService searchService = SearchService.Service;
            if (searchProxy != null)
            {
                // Get the search service application info object so we can find the Id of our Search Service App
                SearchServiceApplicationInfo ssai = searchProxy.GetSearchServiceApplicationInfo();

                // Get the application itself
                SearchServiceApplication application = SearchService.Service.SearchApplications.GetValue<SearchServiceApplication>(ssai.SearchServiceApplicationId);

                FederationManager fedManager = new FederationManager(application);
                SearchObjectOwner owner = new SearchObjectOwner(SearchObjectLevel.SPSite, oSPsite.RootWeb);
                Source currentResultSource = fedManager.CreateSource(owner);
                currentResultSource.Name = "ResultTest";
                Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Rules.QueryTransformProperties QueryProperties = new Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Rules.QueryTransformProperties();
                currentResultSource.CreateQueryTransform(QueryProperties, "");
                currentResultSource.ProviderId = fedManager.ListProviders()["Local SharePoint Provider"].Id;
                currentResultSource.Commit();
            }
        }
```

and I am getting following error.

> The type
>   'Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplication'
>   cannot be used as type parameter 'U' in the generic type or method
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedObjectCollection.GetValue(System.Guid)'.
>   There is no implicit reference conversion from
>   'Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplication'
>   to 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedObject'.

Error is showing at below line from above code.

```
 SearchServiceApplication application = SearchService.Service.SearchApplications.GetValue<SearchServiceApplication>(ssai.SearchServiceApplicationId);
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be missing an assembly reference, make sure your project is referencing both *Microsoft.Office.Server* and *Microsoft.Office.Server.Search*.

Answer (score 0):

This code is working on my VM which has SharePoint 2013 installed. I am assuming you have SharePoint 2013 Server installed where this code is executing.

Comment: Yes. I have SP 2013 Server installed in my VM.